# program calling Sleep doesn't wakup on signals

Tags: winapi

In Linux when an executing thread calling 'sleep' suspends its execution. As soon as a signal is sent to the process the 'sleep' function returns immediately. I can install my signal handler and set the flag below properly to exit the while loop.

```
// a signal handler set 'flag' on CTRL-C

while(flag) {
   sleep(10); // returns on signal caught
}
```

In Windows I cannot see that. I am using 'Sleep(DWORD milliseconds)' and I have installed my signal handler using 'signal' function. Essentially the sleeping threads resumes only at the end of 'Sleep'.

What do I have to do to allow 'Sleep' to return before hand in my code?
Am I using the right approach (using a flag to exit the while loop) or do I have to look at something else?

Comment: I didn't even know that WIndows had *nix-style signals :(

Comment: ..and no, whatever you are doing, polling for a flag is NOT the correct approach.  It's wasteful of CPU and adds avoidable latency, (an average 5ms in your case).  Windows has plenty synchro objects.  A semaphore wait would almost certainly work.

Comment: Also, the flag would need to be volatile.  Forget the flag, read up on Windows synchro and do it properly:)

Comment: use [`SleepEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686307(v=vs.85).aspx) with *bAlertable=TRUE* and function return when *APC* will be inserted. if you use `ZwDelayExecution` direct (this api and call `Sleep[Ex]`) you also can break wait by alert - `ZwAlertThread`

Comment: Once you stop calling sleep, then things will look up for you

Comment: To put things into numerical perspective then, assuming that there is CPU free your average latency will be 5ms.  Using a semaphore wait, under the same conditions, will be ~1000 times faster.

Comment: *I didn't even know that Windows had *nix-style signals* @ThingyWotsit, it doesn't, but Microsoft's C runtime does have C-style signals, since they're part of the ISO standard.  The control-C signal is the only one that is generated as a response to something that happens outside of the process.

Comment: @HarryJohnston oh... OK, thanks for info:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using an [event object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655(v=vs.85).aspx).

Replace your loop with a call to [WaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx), and have the control-C handler call [SetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211(v=vs.85).aspx).

(Of course, in practice it is unlikely that you really want your program to sit and wait, doing nothing, until the user presses control-C.  But that's the scenario the question presents, and this answer gives you a starting point for more realistic scenarios.)